# How to listen to StreamedResponse upload in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `MultipartRequest` and the final step is to use the `send()` method, but I want to be able to display the upload progress.

How do I convert the `StreamedResponse` the `send()` method gives to the bytes sent like a Stream listen method?

I tried this but it doesn't work as intended, it only gives the response from the server, not the upload progress stream.

```
requestMultiPart
                                        .send()
                                        .asStream()
                                        .listen((stream) {
                                      print('Started.');
                                      var received = 0;
                                      final length = stream.contentLength!;
                                      print(length);

                                      stream.stream.listen((bytesUploaded) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          received += bytesUploaded.length;

                                          _progress =
                                              (received / length).toDouble();
                                          print('$_progress%');
                                        });
                                      });
                                    });
```

Basically I need the stream that the upload creates, not the final response stream.

Comment: server's response is created after all the data is received so you cannot use it, you can listen for a upload progress by using this `MultipartFile` ctor: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.html

Comment: @pskink Thank you, however I am stuck on trying to create a Stream from a File object or Uint8list. Do you have an example for me please? I assume I pass the `Stream<List<int>>` to the constructor but first make it a broadcast stream so I can listen to it.

Comment: `final stream = File(some path).openRead().map((data) {print(data.length); return data;})` - of course instead of `print(...)` you should handle the progress in any way you like - no need for a broadcast stream at all

Comment: @pskink This helps and I was able to get a progress bar working, but I noticed the progress bar or bytes iterated in the map method fill all the way through very quickly for a 100MB+ file, but then after it is complete only then the data starts getting uploaded to the endpoint and takes a while till it is complete. If I'm not mistaken this method is for the progress of the browser reading the file fully before uploading, not the upload itself? Here's how I did your suggestion: https://codeshare.io/EBA8o8 , I then used the send method.

Comment: @pskink Regarding `data.length` rather than average it seems to be a static figure: `1000000`, and it goes through that size rapidly and completes the total size (unlike an upload speed). `file.size` does seem to be in bytes as the actual file is about 150MB~, and when `file.size` is printed it says `154122778`.

Comment: strange, so it seems that 150MB is cached somewhere on the client side? cached and then uploaded? it would be a huge waste of resources

Comment: @pskink Correct, definitely something like that whereas the actual upload takes place outside when the stream completes. It's alright, I'll wait for a solution on Flutter Web, for now it seems it is very much requested.

Comment: Ok but what about huge files like 1 or 2 GB? I cannot imagine that first the whole huge content is read and then uploaded?

Comment: Btw you pass `requestMultipart.contentLength` as upload length which is not correct imho, it should be `file.size` that is 150MB

Comment: @pskink I think I figured the problem because of how you are wording this, I am definitely doing something stupid on creating the stream. Take a look at the code again now, I added a snippet: codeshare.io/EBA8o8 . I am using the File Picker package and using its readStream feature. So it the stream I'm using is definitely just the File Picker reading the file first, not the upload. Sorry if I am being a bother, but since dart:io is unusable in Flutter Web, how do I create the Stream<List<int>> for the constructor now? Since `File()` and `openRead` is io? I was going the wrong route.

Comment: what file picker? send it's pub.dev url

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker
And even though I changed it to `file.size`, the cached problem or so is the same.

Comment: so you used https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/file_picker/PlatformFile/readStream.html instead of `File(...).openRead()`?

Comment: @pskink Yes that's right. `openRead` causes a holdup and exception on Flutter Web as they say you can't use dart:io in Flutter web. So I had to go with readStream from this package.

Comment: Yep I missed you are on flutter web, btw tried to upload 2 GB or so? Btw on codeshare.io/EBA8o8 still the length is `requestMultipart.contentLength` and not real file size (150mb)

Comment: @pskink Ah yes I didn't alter it there, but it's correct in my code to `file.size`.  I just tried a 2.57GB file, and it still speeds through, just slightly slower. I got an exception this time though repeatedly throughout the speeding through: `RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed`. I think that means it's too big. But yeah I think it's caching it first.

Comment: Ok so maybe try `dio` package, it has something called "interceptors" (or maybe it simply doesn't cache the stream before upload - you could test it first)

Comment: I even checked it's docs and found sample code named: `"Listening the uploading progress:"` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @pskink for all the help, the solution to get upload progress is as simple as using the `Dio` package: https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Sample code for a mp4 video upload:

```
final dio = Dio();

  final formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'File': MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      file.bytes as List<int>,
      filename: fileName,
      contentType: MediaType("video", "mp4"),
    ),
  });

  final response = await dio.post(
    'https://url.com/',
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        'API-KEY': dotenv.env['API-KEY']!,
      },
      responseType: ResponseType.stream,
    ),
    data: formData,
    onSendProgress: (count, total) {
      progress.percentage = (count / total).toDouble();
      progress.notify();    // Your state manager of choice to update the state.
    },
  );
```

**Important Note:** Dio will not be able to upload large files.

Comment: good to know it just works,  btw, does it work with your huge 2.5GB file? if not, does `MultipartFile.fromStream` ctor change anything? I would like to know if `dio` also reads the whole file first and then uploads... :-(

Comment: @pskink It doesn't actually when I checked just now with the huge file. The error occurs at the `file.bytes as List<int>` part where it's null. Also looks like the filepicker package users confirm caching: https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/561. I would need help to figure out `MultipartFile.fromStream`, it takes in a function: `Stream<List<int>> Function()` and I'm not sure how I can convert `readStream` from the filepicker to a function stream.

Comment: `MultipartFile.fromStream(() => pickedFile.readStream, pickedFile.size, ...)`

Comment: @pskink That worked, but no dice. I get `RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed`, it seems the file is too large to cache. See this: https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/893. He says he fixed it by using a chunk uploader which was this package: https://pub.dev/packages/chunked_uploader.

Comment: where does this `RangeError` occur? what source file? the issue you linked is since he uses `http.MultipartFile`, not `dio.MultipartFile`

Comment: @pskink Here's the console output: https://pastebin.com/CCYNBfXD. And yes you're right, it's not Dio my bad. Since it's Flutter web I don't get a proper breakpoint in an exception, not sure why, I'll check on it.

Comment: @pskink I used the chunked uploader and it works perfectly, here's my code: https://codeshare.io/X86zez. It starts uploading immediately and I can see the request headers in the developer tools where it's uploading in portions. Looks like caching is indeed the cause.

Comment: can you run this with your huge file: `_foo() async {
final files = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(withReadStream: true);
final file = files!.files.first;
int i = 0;
int size = 0;
file.readStream!.listen((event) {
print('chunk #$i: ${event.length}');
i++;
size += event.length;
}, onDone: () => print('file successfully read: ${file.size} == $size'));
}` if it works it means that `file_picker` is not broken and the problem is indeed in `dio` package (its a shame that neither `http` nor `dio` do that the right way...)

Comment: anyway, thanks for that `ChunkedUploader` as it is the only option for any files (small and huge) and not `http` nor `dio`, i hope `dio` devs should do something with that... btw can you edit your answer noting that `dio` cannot upload huge files?

Comment: @pskink Good thinking, I tried the code and yes it loads in the 2GB+ file albeit a bit slow but it finishes no issue. The problem then only occurs in Dio as you said. Hopefully they fix this yes, so you believe the issue is with the file size where Dio has an issue with it and not a caching issue with Dio? I tried to run the Dio request in the `onDone` of the listener you gave but even after it is fully loaded it still shows as `null`. If the issue is it's trying to upload before fully loading in the file, then if it's possible to pass in the fully cached file to Dio, could it work?

Comment: no, you cannot use fully cached file, it is too big: you have to upload in in chunks - in that case 1MB chunks